# use unique id in ajax without json

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, json

The ajax request functions where:

```
success: function(data) {
   $('#totalvotes1').text(data); 
}
```

and where `<span id="totalvotes1">`,

but I need it to work with unique id's where:

```
success: function(data) { 
    $('#total_' + $(this).attr("id")). text(data); 
}
```

and where `<span id="total_vote_up_<?php echo $mes_id; ?>">`

and `<a id="vote_up_<?php echo $mes_id1; ?>">`

I cannot figure out what is wrong with the following code. If anybody has an easy fix with json I would try that but I have no idea how json works. I would love it if somebody could just help me debug this code here

general.js:

```
$(".vote").click(function() 
{
    var id = $(this).attr("id");
    var name = $(this).attr("name");
    var eData = $(this).attr("data-options");
    var dataString = 'id='+ id + '&' + eData ;
    var parent = $(this);

    if(name=='up')
    {
        $(this).fadeIn(200).html('');
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "up.php",
            data: dataString,
            cache: false,

            success: function(data) { 
                $('#total_' + $(this).attr("id")).text(data); 
            }
        });
    }

});
});
});
```

index.php

```
<div id="main">
<div id="left">
    vote_up_<?php echo $mes_id1; ?>
<span class='up'><a id="vote_up_<?php echo $mes_id1; ?>" class="vote" name="up" data-options="key1=<?php echo $mes_id1;?>&key2=<?php echo $mes_id2;?>&key3=<?php echo $totalvotes1;?>&key4=<?php echo $totalvotes2;?>"> <img src="up.png" alt="Down" /></a></span><br />
<span id="total_vote_up_<?php echo $mes_id1; ?>"><?php echo $totalvotes1; ?></span><br />
</div>
<div id="message">
    <?php echo $message1; ?>
</div>
<div class="clearfix"></div>
 </div>
```

Comment: I would try to remove `$(this).attr("id")` from inside the success function and store it in a variable.

Comment: What exactly is the problem?  You say it doesn't work... *what* doesn't work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Identation and enters are your friends.

Try doing something like this:

```
// Before $.ajax
var that = this;
// Inside success
$('#total_' + $(that).attr("id")).text(data);
```

Most jQuery functions change the context, so "this" inside the success function does not point to the ".vote" element. You have to save the reference to the element (usually with something like "var that = this") and use this reference inside the success function.

Edit:

As Matt Burland pointed out, you already have both the clicked element reference saved (parent) and the id saved, so this can be solved with something like:

```
$('#total_' + id).text(data);
```

Comment: In fact, the OP already has this line `var parent = $(this);`, so they could just use `parent.attr("id")).text(data);`

Comment: @MattBurland you are correct hadn't noticed it, $(parent).attr("id") should work aswell.

Comment: omg... so much better than posting to stackoverflow at 2AM.... thank you so much guys. I do not understand at all why this is this case, but it works! I'll read into this later but thank you!

Comment: @cernunnosis there any way to do this and have the `success: function(data) { 
    $('#total_' + $(this).attr("id")). text(data); 
}` return another value back to a different id in the same function?

Comment: @cernunnos like with the data-options on the link or something? define another key and use that in the ajax?

Comment: @MattBurland can I change what is displayed in a span with another id with this in the same ajax success function?

Comment: @PatrickLawler: Not sure *exactly* what you mean. Perhaps you should ask another question on it and explain better (with HTML). But in principle, sure.

Comment: @PatrickLawler So long as you get a valid selector you can manipulate it on your ajax success, the main problem with your initial code was that you where using "this" inside the success callback, and inside that function "this" no longer refered to the button you clicked, so it had no id attribute

Comment: @MattBurland, @cernunnos yea... just don't know how to get a valid selector... I was gonna try to use `<a title="vote_down_<?php echo $mes_id2;?> on the link and then add `$('#total_' + parent.attr("id")).text(data);` to the ajax but I don't know how to change the javascript and the php file to echo a different value to it

Comment: @MattBurland I reposted my question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15012675/change-two-html-ids-with-one-ajax-function

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".vote").click(function() 
{

var id = $(this).attr("id");
var name = $(this).attr("name");
var eData = $(this).attr("data-options");
var dataString = 'id='+ id + '&' + eData ;
var parent = $(this);


if(name=='up')
{

$(this).fadeIn(200).html('');
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "up.php",
data: dataString,
cache: false,

success: function(data) { $('#total_'+id).text(data); } // here is the change

});

}

});
});
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Cleaned up and fixed. Note, instead of keep doing `$(this)`, you can do it once, store it in a variable and use it again. This is much more efficient because it avoids the overhead of repeatedly creating jQuery objects (which is what `$(...)` does).

```
$(".vote").click(function() 
{
    var parent = $(this);   //Note: calling this parent is really confusing!
    var id = parent.attr("id");
    var name = parent.attr("name");
    var eData = parent.data("options");
    var dataString = 'id='+ id + '&' + eData ;

    if(name=='up')
    {

        parent.fadeIn(200).html('');
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "up.php",
            data: dataString,
            cache: false,

            success: function(data) { $('#total_' + id).text(data); }

        });

    }

});
```

Note: The reason your original didn't work is that the `this` in the context of the AJAX callback isn't the same `this` as in the context of the `.click` handler. When you callback is executed, `this` is your browser window, not the element that was originally clicked on.

So, how does this fix it? It makes use of closures. If you have a function (like you AJAX callback) nested inside another function, the inner function has access to all the variables defined in the outer function. So by caching your `id` in the `id` variable, you have access to it when the AJAX callback is called. Even better, even if you where to click on another `.vote` before the callback from the original click is called, it still remembers the correct value!

Comment: ahhhhhh damnit I knew it was something like that but didn't know how to fix it.... im new to all of this... thanks guys!

Comment: @PatrickLawler: Don't feel bad. I'm pretty sure that *every single* JavaScript programmer has been tripped up by `this` at some point.