# change two html id's with one ajax function

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax, json

I need to add something to my ajax request to show it subtracting 1 from `<span id="total_vote_down_<?php echo $mes_id2; ?>">` right now my ajax just adds 1 to the value of `<span id="total_vote_up_<?php echo $mes_id1; ?>">` and I need it to subtract 1 from `<span id="total_vote_up_<?php echo $mes_id1; ?>">`in the same function. I know my code is sloppy as heck.... bear with me...

btw I know the ajax isn't actually adding and subtracting anything and that it is just demonstrating it for the client, just didn't know any better way to phrase my problem

general.js

```
$(".vote").click(function() 
{

var id = $(this).attr("id");
var name = $(this).attr("name");
var eData = $(this).attr("data-options");
var dataString = 'id='+ id + '&' + eData ;
var parent = $(this);


if(name=='up')
{

$(this).fadeIn(200).html('');
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "up.php",
data: dataString,
cache: false,

success: function(data) { $('#total_' + parent.attr("id")).text(data); }
});

}
else
{

$(this).fadeIn(200).html('');
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "down.php",
data: dataString,
cache: false,

success: function(data) { $('#total_' + parent.attr("id")).text(data); }

});


}

});
```

index.php

```
<div id="main">
<div id="left">
<span class='up'><a title="vote_down_" id="vote_up_<?php echo $mes_id1; ?>" class="vote" name="up" data-options="key1=<?php echo $mes_id1;?>&key2=<?php echo $mes_id2;?>&key3=<?php echo $totalvotes1;?>&key4=<?php echo $totalvotes2;?>"> <img src="up.png" alt="Down" /></a></span><br />
<span id="total_vote_up_<?php echo $mes_id1; ?>"><?php echo $totalvotes1; ?></span><br />
</div>
<div id="message">
    <?php echo $message1; ?>
</div>
<div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>
<div id="main">
<div id="right">
<br />
<span id="total_vote_down_<?php echo $mes_id2; ?>"><?php echo $totalvotes2; ?></span><br />
<span class='down'><a id="vote_down_<?php echo $mes_id2; ?>" class="vote" name="down" data-options="key1=<?php echo $mes_id1;?>&key2=<?php echo $mes_id2;?>"><img src="down.png" alt="Down" /></a></span>
</div>
<div id="message">
    <?php echo $message2; ?>
</div>
<div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>
```

here is up.php

```
<?php

session_start();
include("config.php");

$ip=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; 

$mes_id1 = $_POST['key1'];
$mes_id2 = $_POST['key2'];
$totalvotes1 = $_POST['key3'];
$totalvotes2 = $_POST['key4'];
$new_totalvotes1 = $totalvotes1 + 1;
$new_totalvotes2 = $totalvotes2 - 1;

$ip_sql=mysql_query("select ip_add from Voting_IP where mes_id_fk='$mes_id1' and ip_add='$ip'");
$count=mysql_num_rows($ip_sql);

$ip_sql2=mysql_query("select ip_add from Voting_IP where mes_id_fk='$mes_id2' and ip_add='$ip'");
$count2=mysql_num_rows($ip_sql2);


// if the user has already voted, execute script
if($count==0 && $count2!=0)
{
$sql = "update Messages set totalvotes=totalvotes+1  where mes_id='$mes_id1'";
mysql_query( $sql);

$sql_in = "insert into Voting_IP (mes_id_fk,ip_add) values ('$mes_id1','$ip')";
mysql_query( $sql_in);

$sql = "update Messages set totalvotes=totalvotes-1  where mes_id='$mes_id2'";
mysql_query( $sql);

$sql_in = "DELETE FROM Voting_IP WHERE mes_id_fk='$mes_id2'";
mysql_query( $sql_in);

echo $new_totalvotes1;

// if the user has not voted, execute script
}
else if($count==0 && count2==0)
{
$sql = "update Messages set totalvotes=totalvotes+1  where mes_id='$mes_id1'";
mysql_query( $sql);

$sql_in = "insert into Voting_IP (mes_id_fk,ip_add) values ('$mes_id1','$ip')";
mysql_query( $sql_in);

echo $new_totalvotes1;

}
?>
```

down.php is the same as up just with opposite values

Comment: So it looks like your `up.php` (and, presumably `down.php`) returns the current number of votes for the one item clicked on and you have a dependency that when one of these is clicked up, you need to change the down count too (presumably when somebody previously voted down and changes their mind). Perhaps your best approach would be to have your PHP function return a JSON response with the `id` and `votes` for each affect item and have your AJAX success function parse that?

Comment: EXACTLY!!! good thing I have no idea how to do that lol, would you be able to help me implement some JSON here....? thank you so much @MattBurland

Comment: Use [json_encode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php). You can create an associative array in PHP and echo it back using `json_encode`. Then if you set you AJAX call to `json`, jQuery will convert it into a JavaScript object for you.

Comment: btw just in case it brings any clarification to what I'm trying to do, the down and up aspects of my code are really going to be attributed to Will and Henry, lol users are going to be able to vote for who they think "won" each of their podcast debates... this site is for my brother... I'm doing it all for free but I want to do a killer job for him

Comment: @MattBurland so... I put `$array1 = array($totalvotes1, $totalvotes2);
print_r($array1);` in my up.php file.... that's as far as I understand... where/how do I echo it back with `json_encode`...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you create an associative array in PHP, you can use `json_encode` to convert it to JSON. Something like this:

```
// obviously this will be constructed dynamically from your database
$d = array('Will' => 10, 'Henry' => 12);
// echo as json
echo json_encode($d);
```

Then in your JavaScript:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "down.php",
    data: dataString,
    cache: false,
    dataType: "json",

    success: function(data) { 
        // here data will look like { "Will":10, "Henry": 20 };
        // I'm going to assume `total_will` is the total votes for william
        var candidate;
        for (candidate in data) {
            $("#total_" + candidate).text(data[candidate]);
        }
        // now #total_Will has the text 10
        // and #total_Henry has the text 20
    }
});
```

Comment: how does javascript know what for(candidate in data) is..?

Comment: @PatrickLawler: It'll know if you set up the ids in your HTML so that you can easily construct it from the data you receive.